# Xcode 6.1.1 with Swift - Not generating preview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am working on Xcode 6.1.1 with Swift. I just build a test application to verify if things are working well and what I see is that, Xcode neither generates a preview nor the `Main.stroryboard` elements show up when I run the app on the simulator.

P.S. Main Interface is set `Main.stroryboard`


[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't set up any constraints. Select your `Storyboard` interface and disable `Size Classes` if you do not wish to take advantage of the new feature based on constraints.

[image]

Otherwise create constraints to set up the position of your objects correctly. Your `UILabel` and `UITextField` need the `Center Horizontally` constraint. Then, set up the `top space` constraint for the `UILabel` and the `bottom space` constraint for the `UITextField`.

Comment: It worked! How to fix my issue without disabling `Size Classes` ?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. In the second part I explained how to create the right constraints for your project.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Just check "is initial view controller"in attributes inspector once

Comment: It is. Look closely at his posted image. You can see an arrow there.

Comment: may be the view is embedded in a nav con and the arrow is coming from nav con?